# Recommendation system based on users past experience

Tags: dataframe, recommendation-engine

I'm currently working on making a recommendation system. I have all the information about what kind of books the  user views. How do I build a recommendation system using that information?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Question seems very general to me. If you're using python I would suggest you to check out the following link:

https://realpython.com/build-recommendation-engine-collaborative-filtering/

Recommendations can be created using 'collaborative filtering' where you determine similarities of users or items.

The source uses scikit-surprise which is a ready to use implementation with all code needed for a recomendation system.
The surprise library is good if you have (explicit) book ratings whereas another library called 'implicit' is better for implicit ratings within the data e.g. if the user viewed or liked something.

https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

https://benfred.github.io/implicit/index.html

It really depends on your usecase, both libraries have implemented various algorithms for your task, so you need to find the solution that fits best.
There are also lots of other libraries and implementations blogs and more on the internet but that's what I would start with.